# How can I extract ticket number from header element

Tags: python, database, selenium, xpath, getattribute

[another text header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GLhW.png)I want use header and split digit numbers in header title but i cant print header I have to take numbers of searching it by link ;
[[html class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEgOg.png)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo2Ja.png)

Please help..

```
try:
    header = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'details__header-title')   
    print(header) 
    for c in (header):
    #    if c.isdigit():
            print(c)
except:
    header2 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'ticket-message__body-message--text')
    print(header2)
    for a in (header2):
#if a.isdigit():
            print(a)
```

Comment: Please show the code (as properly formatted text) that you're having trouble with

Comment: try:
    header = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'details__header-title')   
    print(header) 
    for c in (header):
    #    if c.isdigit():
            print(c)
except:
    header2 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'ticket-message__body-message--text')
    print(header2)
    for a in (header2):
#if a.isdigit():
            print(a)

Comment: i tried by classname , tag name , and partial link but i didnt work

Comment: Please put this inside the question as formatted code to make it readable

Comment: And if possible please share the link to that page to allow debugging

Comment: @phantompain Code is very difficult to read when placed in Comments. Please update your question

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: try `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.details__header-title')`

Comment: Css selector didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**
Since all the desired header elements having `details__header-title` class and you want to get the ticket number appearing in the text in that element you can locate this element, extract it text and then extract number from the string, as following:

```py
text_content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'details__header-title').text
ticket_number = int(''.join(sign for sign in text_content if sign.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Every header titles are different . in your code after text(),' if it possible you can cancel text not same in every tickets.

Comment: Well, you did not share this information. I can't see what is going on on the page you working on. What is fixed, what is changing, what is unique etc.

Comment: i added another header

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to do there and what is the problem?

Comment: Tickets are coming in my admin panel I wrote code and when updated page clicking unreaded tickets but then i cant take header title to in my code, if i take it i will check order with another code. in header there is order number, every title is different and has different order numbers.

Comment: Not so clear... I'm sorry

Comment: I have admin panel, in admin panel customers if they have issue with their orders creating support ticket. a lot ticket coming in day and i want create bot for auto answer according to order number. Order number is in header. I wrote a code. in code if there is unreaded  ticket  my code opening it  automatically  but my problem is i want it order number for use next code. in my next code i want take this number in header and search it automaticly in orders

Comment: OK, the `details__header-title` class name is common for all those headers and you want to extract the number from text of that element?

Comment: Yes sir excatly i want it

Comment: OK, let me know if the updated answer resolved your problem. And.... learn how to define your question clearly :)

Comment: ticket_number = int(filter(str.isdigit, text_content))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'filter'

Comment: it was so close ...... almost we done this error given

Comment: You are right, I did not check what I posted. Not it should work.

Comment: Have you tried the updated answer?

Comment: You are the best just i can say it <333333333333333333333333

Comment: im still working on it still, i need some one help @prophet

Comment: Hi! Please open a new question for that. I'll try helping if I will have time. Maybe also someone else will be able to help. It's always better to ask a new question so many people will see it and will try to help